# Determine sign of the remainder for Taylor expansion

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions

Consider the following function $\rho(x)$ (which we define using intermediary variables and functions) for $0 < u, v < 1/4$ and $x$ some positive number

```
r := Sqrt[(1 - u)*(1 - v)]
s[x_] := Sqrt[(1/2 - u * x)*(1/2 - v*x)]
rho[x_] := (1/2)*(r + s[x] + 1/2 + Sqrt[(r - 1/2 -  s[x])^2 + 4 * u * v * x])
```

I would like to lower bound $\rho$ and from plotting it seems that the first second order Taylor expansion is a proper lower bound for it. From Taylor I have that

$\rho(x) = \rho(0) + x\rho'(0) + R_2$ where $R_2$ is the remainder. I would like to prove that this remainder $R_2$ is positive using Mathematica, as if I manage to do that them I will have $\rho(x) \geq \rho(0) + x\rho'(0)$ which is the lower bound I seek.